Help with chicken door automation circuit
i'm designing a circuit to automate the open and close of a chicken coop door.
The door is a self-build wooden door which slides up and down, guided by two aluminium profiles, very similar to this one:

NOTE: I'm absolutely not a electronic/circuit expert, i have electronics background by playing with arduino/esp32 but definitely not an electronic guy.
I plan to attach a motor to the door to pull the door up and release it down, but i need a driving circuit, which i hope it should accomplish these goals:

must work without microcontrollers (manually operated by buttons)
optionally can be integrated with some arduino/esp for auto open/close
should draw less current possible when idle (like all the day except for one minute in the moring and one in the evening)
should be the easier possible, because in case it stops working, the lower amount of checks should be made to restore it.
Hopefully motor should not burn out by overcurrent.

The circuit i came up is this:

Some notes:

Motor is this one: (12V, 10RPM, 1.6A rated amps) https://it.aliexpress.com/item/1005005424749042.html?spm=a2g0o.order_list.order_list_main.17.11173696YIY17I&gatewayAdapt=glo2ita
The door will be pulled up with a rope and fall down by gravity.
Buttons will be pressed for the entire motion time.
the motor driver is this one: https://www.pololu.com/product/4035
Optocouplers are added because long cables are powered with 12V, while the motor driver requires 5V. The diodes before the optocouplers are there just to perform some kind of protection
micro switches on open and close should stop the motor when the door is fully open/closed
The motor driver have integrated overcurrent protection, and shorts the pin nFault to ground when this happens. In that case, a couple of transistors are added to short to ground the input signal and stop the motor.
"Long cables" means something around 10m, while short cables something around 30cm (the front panel of the box where the circuit will be)

Does this circuit shows some criticlities?
Are there suggestions for other schemes?
Thanks!

You need a lot of capacitance for your circuit, because the motor will draw so much current that the voltage drops dramatically. You may also want to separate the motor supply and circuit supply for that reason.

Was planning to use this power supply: https://us.rs-online.com/product/mean-well/rd-65a/70406962/. Provides himself dual voltage  with 3A at 12V, while motor draws 1.6A at rated load. Is it not enough?

Might be enough (you must check the motor specs). But important is to separate supplies and provide huge caps.

Maybe you can improve your protection circuit by using a zener diode instead of a schottky?

If EN_TO_GND goes zero, you might have a short circuit from 5V to GND across U10 output.

Updated the schematics in first message.

Q1 and Q2 are wrong polarity. You might want NPN.

Why npn? The nFault pin is a open-drain pulled low on fault (see https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/drv8874.pdf page 3), and is pulled up on working condition. If i use a npn then PH and EN are shorted to ground by default and no signal will ever reach the motor driver? Am i wrong?

You don‘t need a transistor in this case. The nFAULT pin can be connected to EN. It will pull EN low in case of a fault. But you still need the pull-up resistor to 5V. And pnp is clearly wrong.
